# Memory error while resizing CIFAR-10 dataset

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, resize

I am using transfer learning to classify a CIFAR-10 dataset using pre-trained ResNet50 model. But the problem is this model accepts minimum size of (197,197) and CIFAR-10 dataset size is (32,32). So I am resizing the model to (200,200) using this code

```
# Reshaping the training data
X_train_new = np.array([misc.imresize(X_train[i], (200, 200, 3)) for i in range(0, len(X_train))]).astype('float32')

# Preprocessing the data, so that it can be fed to the pre-trained ResNet50 model. 
resnet_train_input = preprocess_input(X_train_new)

# Creating bottleneck features for the training data
train_features = model.predict(resnet_train_input)

# Saving the bottleneck features
np.savez('resnet_features_train', features=train_features)
```

Is there any efficient way to do this as it causes a `MemoryError` to be raised. Here is the traceback:

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>         1 #Reshaping the training data
>   ----> 2 X_train_new = np.array([misc.imresize(X_train[i], (200, 200, 3)) for i in range(0, len(X_train))]).astype('float32')
>         3 
>         4 #Preprocessing the data, so that it can be fed to the pre-trained ResNet50 model.
>         5 resnet_train_input = preprocess_input(X_train_new)
>
> MemoryError:

Comment: I don't know how ResNet50 works but since your entire dataset does not fit into memory, you might consider resizing and saving it in several batches of smaller size.

Comment: It's not so much about the network architecture but the dataset. I guess @taras answer is already pretty good in that it points you to batching, but I would honestly resize them before, store them, and not do the whole computation "on the fly" each time.